Why does the website we are working on looks fine on their side but not on mine?
We are working on our Capstone project and two of us are in charge of designing the frontend of the website.
I asked my partner to create the burger for our site. It looks fine on his side but it looks broken on mine.
We are working on the same Github Repo.
here are the pictures:
My side
His side
HAMBURGER in HTML
        <div class="navigation">
            <button class="hamburger" onclick="show()">
                <div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
                <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
                <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
            </button>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#main">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="otp.html">REPORT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">LOGIN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

HAMBURGER CSS
a,button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 250px;
}

.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -475px;
    left: -500px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: .5s;
}

.navigation ul li{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #252525;
}

.hamburger, .bar{
    position: fixed;
}

.hamburger{
    display: block;
    top: 5%;
    right: 95%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border: 0;
    background: 0 0;
}

.bar{
    top: 3px;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

#bar2{
    top: 11px;
}

#bar3{
    top: 19px;
}

.navigation.active{
    left: 0;
}

.hamburger.open #bar1{
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(6px, 5px);
}

.hamburger.open #bar2{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.hamburger.open #bar3{
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(6px, -5px);
}


Just a comment rather than a solution: put your code through a validator - you shouldn't have divs as children of a button.

Have you forgotten to show what happens when the user clicks? Please make your code into a runnable snippet and test to make sure it shows the problem. A snippet makes it much easier for us to provide a solution that fits your particular circumstance.

Your navigation has position: fixed property which means it will appear the same no matter the screen size. So it may seem okay on your partner side but as your screen size if not the same as his it will broke on it
Solution :
You may make the positioning position: relative and adjust rest of the thing accordingly which then  should work on both of your personal displays
